# Property 'find' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/productcatelog2/src/client/app/shared/product.model")'.ts'

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

iam a newbee here ,i managed to apply route for the created products but it is unable to view the specific product while clicked

**product-details.component.html**

here product-details has routed then ".find" emmits error .

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
//import { Product } from '../shared/product.model';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//import { ApiService }from '../shared/api.service';

//import { products } from '../products';
import * as products from '../shared/product.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit
{
  //products: Array<Product>;
  product;


  constructor(
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
   // private http : ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
    const productitemNameFromRoute = String(routeParams.get('productitemName'));


    this.product = products.find(product => product.itemName === productitemNameFromRoute);

    }
  }
```

**product.model.ts**

```
export interface Product 
{
  itemName: string;
  category: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
  isStockAvailable:boolean;
  photoUrl:string;
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

here is the tsconfig.json  are its need to modify

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "es6"
   },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the `products` variable defined? Please show more info.

Comment: also tried by changing the target to es6 on tsconfig.json

Comment: products: Array<Product>;@Michael D

Comment: Should be `this.products.find`. Currently it tries to use that products -> `import * as products`.

Comment: nope if i mod this.products.find it emits error on "products"